# How to get an image only from DCIM directory

Tags: android

I'm getting all images from SD card but now I only want to show the pictures taken with the camera (in the DCIM folder).

Is it possible to do that ?

Answer (score 16):

Try:

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getAbsolutePath()
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM;
```

[Official Doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#DIRECTORY_DCIM)

Here is a link for more info : [Using Android’s external storage effectively and judiciously](http://mbcdev.com/2013/04/13/using-androids-external-storage-effectively-and-judiciously/)

Comment: but in DCIM there is many folders like : if you download any image from facebook then it is place in this folder or many different folders in it. So my question is how i know that only camera captured image folder path? In HTC phones there is 100Media in place of Camera folder.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can try to do this:

```
new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "DCIM")
```

Also it's possible to use something like `Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM`